# Is the apostrophe in the title "Demon's souls" misused?

Tags: apostrophe

The title for the game as advertised is [**Demon's Souls**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon%27s_Souls), which in my understanding translates to "Demon is souls" which is relatively wrong, *I think*.

Rather it should be written like **Demons Souls**, which then translates to "the souls of the demons", so it sound right.

Is title correctly written or should it be corrected as I've mentioned?

Comment: But 'John's bananas' can mean 'the bananas belonging to John' (and hopefully does) rather than ''John is crazy'. [Why do we say 'a hotel room' and not 'a hotel's room'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room) and [St Matthew's Church vs St Matthew Church](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew/134897#134897) may help you with possessives vs attributive usages. And when it comes to choosing names, be glad they didn't choose _D'e*m''o﮺ns S'o﯀ul's_.

Comment: **Demon's souls** can also mean 'more than one soul belonging to one demon'. If the intended meaning is 'the souls of several demons', it should be **Demons' Souls**.

Comment: [Possessives: nouns](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/possessives-nouns)

Answer (score 1):

Many souls belonging to one demon == Demon's souls, or "the souls of the demon" [singular demon, plural souls].
Many souls belonging to many demons == Demons' souls, or "the souls of the demons" [plural demons, plural souls].

The apostrophe drives the possesive in these cases.
The possesive is not the same as the apostrophe used to indicate a missing letter, an [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).

Consider

> John's home.
> John's gone home.

John doesn't posses a 'gone', even though he may possess a 'home'. The first is 'the home of John' the second is descriptive of an action, John[has] gone home. Additional confusion could arise if you consider "John's home" to be an elision of "John **is** home". In such cases you would need to rely on context.

From comments - [Possessives: nouns](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/possessives-nouns)

I can think of no instance in which "Demons souls" would be appropriate.

For sake of completeness - apostrophes in plurals are **always** wrong. This is known as the greengrocer's apostrophe; from their penchant for selling apple's, pear's and banana's.